# Why is GPSd clients not returning data?

Tags: linux, nvidia, gpsd

I'm using a Neo-M9N to get the latitude, longitude, speed, and so on and place these values in a csv file.

I installed the gpsd python clients. I'm able to view the data only using

```
gpsmon /dev/ttyTHS1
```

but can't see it if I only use

```
gpsmon
```

I already changed the `/etc/default/gpsd` file to this:

```
START_DAEMON="true"  
USBAUTO="true" 
DEVICES="/dev/ttyTHS1" 
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G" 
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

I don't know how to fix this, and when I check the status this is what appears:

````
jun 05 17:14:40 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: gpsd.service: Job gpsd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
jun 05 17:14:45 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: Dependency failed for GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon.
jun 05 17:14:45 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: gpsd.service: Job gpsd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
built@jetson-nano-2gb:~$ sudo systemctl status gpsd.socket
● gpsd.socket - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gpsd.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources)
   Listen: /var/run/gpsd.sock (Stream)
           [::1]:2947 (Stream)
           0.0.0.1:2947 (Stream)

jun 05 17:14:40 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: gpsd.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Address already in use
jun 05 17:14:40 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: gpsd.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
jun 05 17:14:40 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: Failed to listen on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.
jun 05 17:14:45 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: gpsd.socket: Failed to listen on sockets: Address already in use
jun 05 17:14:45 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: gpsd.socket: Failed with result 'resources'.
jun 05 17:14:45 jetson-nano-2gb systemd[1]: Failed to listen on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.``` 

Has anyone been able to solve this? Thanks for the help!
````

Comment: It says there in the status that the address that it's listening on is already in use. You need to change the address to one that's not already being used and it will work provided that there aren't other issues.

Comment: I only have it connected to the UART pins on Jetson Nano. I'm only using this UART communication, so what is getting used besides the gps? @NasirRiley

Comment: That's what you need to find out. If there was nothing else using the address, then the error wouldn't appear. If you don't know the command to look for addresses being used, add the port that it's set to listen on and the output of `netstat -taunp | grep PORT` (where PORT is the port number) to your question.